# Python Face_Recognition - Cmake | Dlib Installation Error Windows

Tags: python, computer-vision, face-recognition, dlib

A big thanks for solving my problem.

1) I have Installed **cmake** using:
`pip install cmake` & also using setup from their official Website.
[Added to System and User Environment Vairable Path] : https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5O7w.png

2) Installed Visual Studio 2019 and installed all relevant build Tools & Everything
[Installed All imp Components along with Visual Studio 2019] https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVJdy.png

3) Still Getting Error while installing face_recognition.
I get same error for dlib when i write

```
pip install face_recognition
```

or

```
pip install dlib
```

[error pics] https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5Ril.png | https://i.stack.imgur.com/430YT.png | https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYy70.png |

Comment: https://github.com/davisking/dlib

Comment: Not working !!!!

Comment: go  through solutions in this link https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/issues/339

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to the fact that your machine either does not have a C++ compiler, or the PATH is not set. Hope this helps!